# Modeling heat transfer of a long pipeline with heated fluid and flow as a lumped system with time delay

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, models

I want to model the heat transfer of a very long pipeline and how heated fluid is flowing through this system.
It is possible to model this system as a distributed system.
However I want to model this system as a delayed lumped system as it takes time for the fluid to get from start to end.
However how would one model this kind of system? as a simple Lumped model is highly inaccurate for these kind of things.

The lumped model I used is simply the capacitance of the fluid, advection coming from incoming fluid and convection to the outside due to heat loss.

\begin{equation}
mc\dot{T} = \dot{m}c\Delta T + hA\Delta T 
\end{equation}

kind regards

Comment: In your equation, you use $\Delta T$ both as the change in temperature between inlet and outlet and as the temperature driving force.  Did you really mean to do this?

Comment: No I didn't. Just a mistake. the first delta T should be the difference between inlet and the state and the second delta T should be the difference between the environmental temperature and the state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use $$\rho c\left(\frac{\pi D^2}{4}\right)\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+\dot{m}c\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}=\pi Dh(T_{outside}-T)$$or, equivalently, $$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+v\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}=\frac{4}{D}\frac{h}{\rho c}(T_{outside}-T)$$
where $v=\frac{\dot{m}}{\rho \frac{\pi D^2}{4}}$.

Comment: Could you explain a little how you set up this PDE?

Comment: Somewhere in this forum, I presented the actual transient analytic solution to this problem, subject to the initial condition T=To everywhere, and heat transfer at x > 0 for all time t >0.

Comment: @Gert I wasn't worried about whether you would be able to solve it.  I knew you could.  My comment was directed at the OP.

Comment: Oh, Ok. :-) Thanks.